# What does "line 10: acuteness: command not found" mean and what is wrong with my if statement?

Tags: bash, command-substitution

Here's my script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#read password.lst, hash each word, store in variable and check it against our hash

target_hash="14a4b8e7ae966e72a3a2c51633bfabc6"
password_lst=/usr/share/metasploit-framework/data/wordlists/password.lst

while IFS= read -r password
  do
    hashed_password=printf $password | /usr/bin/md5sum | cut -d  " " -f 1

    if [ $hashed_password == $target_hash ]
                then 
                        printf "==========================\n"
                        printf "Found Password: $password\n"
                        printf "==========================\n"
                        break
                else 
                        printf "Password: $password\n"
                        printf "Target hash: $target_hash\n"
                        printf "Current Hash: $hashed_password\n"
        fi

done < "$password_lst"
```

The purpose is to hash each word in the file `password.lst`, check it against the `target_hash` and if it's correct, output the correct password and until the loop gets there, output what hash it's currently working on.

I keep getting errors in lines 10 and 12. Does anyone know what could be wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line doesn't work the way you might think:

```sh
hashed_password=printf $password | /usr/bin/md5sum | cut -d  " " -f 1
```

The shell sees this as:

- Set the env var `hashed_password` to `printf` and then run `$password` (that is, expand the variable and run the value as a command) with that env vars set
- Pipe the results of the previous step into `/usr/bin/md5sum`
- Pipe the results of the previous step into `cut ....`

What I think you want is to evaluate the whole thing and assign the result into `hashed_pasword`? If so, you need to use this form:

```sh
var=$(evaluate this thing and assign it to the var)
```

So:

```sh
hashed_password=$(printf $password | /usr/bin/md5sum | cut -d  " " -f 1)
```

Comment: Note that `printf $password` is wrong -- it should be `printf '%s' "$password"` if you want to emit the variable contents literally with no trailing newline; as it is, it'll try to treat backslashes, `%`s, etc as format-string elements.